# CMD/Python Syntax Error when attempting to read .py file and create .mp4 output

Tags: python, cmd, visualizer

I am trying to follow the instructions listed in the below link:

https://github.com/msieg/deep-music-visualizer

In short form and from my understanding, it is merging a .py file and .mp3 and creating an .mp4 output file so that there is a music visualizer video to the song selected. The instructions direct you to run the script through the argument through the terminal.

I keep running into syntax errors when attempting to enter the script as instructed.

python visualizer.py -- song beethoven.mp3 -- output_file my_song.mp4

I have confirmed that python is installed and PATH has been directed to the appropriate place.

I have set my working directory to the folder containing the .py file and .mp3

I have also attempted this via the Python command

```
>>> python visualize.py -- song beethoven.mp3 -- output_file my_movie.mp4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python visualize.py -- song beethoven.mp3 -- output_file my_movie.mp4
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

expect the creation of a .mp4 file that includes both the visualizer and song.

The goal is to be able to customize the visualizer to the song via different parameters.

Comment: You are trying to start `python visualize.py ...` from the python console. You should do it from CMD instead.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't as clear. The code reflects the error from CMD. I have also attempted from the python console to no avail.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you were running the python interpreter inside the terminal, which is not the same thing. Close cmd.exe, launch a brand new cmd.exe window, and paste "python visualize.py --song beethoven.mp3 --output_file my_movie.mp4". Then hit enter.